# Primefaces terminal causes java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, primefaces, terminal

My application should show **JBoss** `server.log` file in primefaces terminal. I read the file, but i get the following message:

```
 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.el.ELException: /tmp.xhtml @72,109 commandHandler="#{terminalController.handleCommand(command)}": java.lang.NullPointerException
```

XHTML code:

```
<h:form >
<p:focus for="terminal" /> 
<p:terminal id="terminal" widgetVar="term" commandHandler="#{terminalController.handleCommand(command)}/>
</h:form>
```

Terminal controller:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "terminalController")
public class TerminalController {  

String sCurrentLine;
String sCurrentLineArray[];
Integer i=0;
BufferedReader br;

public TerminalController()  {

}
public String handleCommand(String command) throws IOException,FileNotFoundException {

    this.br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(
                    "/home/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log/server.log"));
    if(command.equals("start")){

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
               return sCurrentLine;
            }
            return "end";
    } 
    else  
            return command + " not found";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring in:

```
 if(command.equals("start")){
  ....
 }
```

I don't know where that `command` comes from, but if it is **null**, and you try to compare it to another string, java will throw an exception.

To fix:

```
if(command != null && command.equals("start"){
....
}
```

You might have check if it's also not empty `if (command != null && !command.isEmpty() && command.equals("start"))`